# xmlNewCDataBlock implicit conversion to int

Tags: objective-c, libxml2

I'm parsing xml via `libxml2` library. After updating `Xcode` to `5.1`, I got warning that last parameter - length - is implicitly converted to `int`, while it's `unsigned long`. 
Here's function declaration:

```
XMLPUBFUN xmlNodePtr XMLCALL
    xmlNewCDataBlock(xmlDocPtr doc,
                     const xmlChar *content,
                     int len);
```

Is there any similar function that takes `unsigned long` values, because I don't know how big my data can be, and I want to process it safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such function. *libxml2*'s [string manipulation functions](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/tree/xmlstring.c) use `int`s for string lengths and offsets, so text nodes longer than `INT_MAX` are not supported.